# Dynamic prepared statement, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I've checked almost all questions that produce the same error but all of these questions bind parameters in some wrong way. Perhaps and most probably I too am binding params incorrectly though my case is different because I've dynamic query.

I am creating query dynamically from input which is being created perfectly. But problem comes from `$stmt->bind_param` statement within `foreach` loop. Here is my Code snippet that is erronous:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET";
        foreach($updationFields as $field => $value){
            if($value != "-"){
                $query = $query. " " . $field . " = :".$field.",";
            }
        }
        $query = rtrim($query, ",");
        $query = $query . " WHERE UserId = :UserId";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        foreach($updationFields as $field => $value){
            echo $field;
            if($value != "-"){
                $input = ":".$field;
                $stmt->bind_param($input, $value); // This line produces error
            }
        }
        $stmt->bind_param(":UserId", $userId);

        $stmt->execute();
```

Here is produced dynamic "string query" for one field:

```
UPDATE users SET fullName = :fullName WHERE UserId = :UserId
```

Error says: **Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in**

Any Idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: In... In what? Do you have a line number?

Comment: `$stmt` is most likely === false because `$query` isnt a valid query.

Comment: you're overwriting your `$query =` each time. Do => `$query .=`

Comment: @castis please check updated question query is produced correctly because I wanted to use `:placeholder` to bind params via foreach.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup but that shouldn't produce error, should it?

Comment: Well `$stmt` is not an object, and its created from a well-formed query so...

Comment: @Fred-ii-, actually not; the original query appears to be concatenated into the newly assigned query each time. Wouldn't hurt to see the final value of the `$query` variable, though.

Comment: `var_dump($query,$stmt);` just before the second `foreach` gives what?

Comment: @helmbert `$query = rtrim($query, ",");
        $query = $query . " WHERE UserId = :UserId";` only the last one gets the hit, and the `,` gets lost. Least, I tend to think so. Unless `= $query .` is doing the concatenate.

Comment: are you using `PDO` or `mysqli`? as `bindParam` and `bind_param` are two very different things

Comment: your prepare call failed, returned boolean false, and since you didn't bother checking for errors, you blindly went on to use that false as if it was an object.

Comment: On the problem line, you should be doing `$stmt->bind_param($input, $updationFields->$field);` because the bind is to a variable, not a value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i used `rtrim` deliberately to remove last unnecessary comman that shouldn't produce error also query produced that i've pasted here is just before prepare so its OK. Though i will use `.= ` next.

Comment: @MarcB query is fine that's why i went blindly let me do proper checking and see what's wrong.

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ: that's how you get in trouble. there's a near infinite number of ways a DB operation can fail, and only ONE way to succeed. Even if the sql itself is 100% perfect, there's far far far too many other ways for problems to come up. never ever assume success. always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ the query you wrote is for `PDO` and not for `mysqli` , check this out, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @cmorrissey augh!!! of course. Staring me right in the face too. I was going to ask the OP earlier if he was using PDO. That's what happens when one stares at code for too long.

Comment: @All i admit my code isn't perfect there are many aspects to improve but as Fredii and cmorrissey said its related to PDO, since i checked query is generated correctly still mysqli won't prepare query that means :placeholder isn't for msyqli its for PDO. Perhaps if someone could suggest how do I make this kind of dynamic binding with mysqli I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Fred-ii- and @commorrissey `:Placeholder` is supported by PDO not mysqli so so I had to:

1. Replace `:Placeholders` with `?`
2. Call `bind_param` with `call_user_func_array` feeding dynamic references as expected by mysqli_stmt.

Here is the code that creates dynamic binding:

```
            $params = array();//
            $params[] = $type;
            $i=0;
            foreach($updationFields as $field => $value){
                if($value != "-"){
                    $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
                    $$bind_name = $value;
                    $params[] = &$$bind_name;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
            $$bind_name = $userId;
            $params[] = &$$bind_name;

            $return = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'), $params);
```

Comment: I have written a class for MySQL PS... https://github.com/DennisWeidmann/SQLContentProvider